# JAX-B Global Binding Ignored in WSDL

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have a WSDL from which I am generating classes in NetBeans.  The unaltered copy has dates, and those dates are generated as XMLGregorianCalendar.  I am trying to override that behavior and insert a globalbinding tag, so that it generates a Java Date instead.  However, no matter where I put the binding tag (shown below), it is ignored, and XMLGregorianCalendar is used as a date type.

Can someone tell me if I am on the right track, and where to place the override?  Below is also the overall layout of the WSDL.

```
<annotation>
    <appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
                      parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate"
                      printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate"
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </appinfo>
</annotation>
```

The redacted WSDL, showing what I believe are the relevant parts:

```
<types>
    <s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sap="http://xyz/sap" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xyz/sap">
        <s:element name="createOrder">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element ref="sap:sap-order-request" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
    </s:schema>

    <xs:schema xmlns:sap="http://xyz/sap" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://xyz/sap" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:element name="sap-order-request">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="publication-date" type="xs:date" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</types>

 <binding name="SapSalesOrderSoap" type="s0:SapSalesOrderSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="createOrder">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://xyz/sap/createOrder" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the namespace prefix on the `<javaType>` element - it needs to be in the JAXB namespace, not the XML Schema or WSDL namespace.